# use an if statement to determine if the team in question has surpassed their goal of 5 reports

Tags: javascript

We are going to complete a function that takes in two parameters, an object containing the report totals for various teams, and the string name of a team, and determines if the given team has surpassed their goal of 5 reports, and if they have, returns a specific string. Your function should use an `if` statement to determine if the team in question has surpassed their goal of 5 reports, and if they have, should return the string `{teamName} has surpassed goal with {number_of_reports_for_team} reports`, where:

- `{teamName}` has the value of the second argument the function is called on;
- `{number_of_reports_for_team}` is the number of reports in the inputted object argument for `{teamName}`.

Below are examples of the code running, assuming that you will have completed the described function: `generateReportSummary`.
Why is the value only choosing the first object?
My code:

```js
function generateReportSummary(reportTotals, teamName) {
  for (key in reportTotals) {
    if (reportTotals[key] > 5) {
      return teamName + ' surpassed goal with ' + reportTotals[key] + ' reports';
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }
  }
}

var result1 = generateReportSummary({
  a_team: 12,
  b_team: 7,
  c_team: 0
}, 'b_team');
console.log('should log "b_team has surpassed goal with 7 reports":', result1);

var result2 = generateReportSummary({
  blue: 18,
  red: 8,
  green: 12
}, 'blue');
console.log('should log "blue has surpassed goal with 18 reports":', result2);

var result3 = generateReportSummary({
  gamma: 1,
  epsilon: 3,
  alpha: 4,
  bravo: 17
}, 'alpha');
console.log('Should log undefined, because function returned nothing:', result3);
```

Comment: how about you read what I asked and look at the work I've done. This isn't my homework, they're exercises I found online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not check every `key` in `reportTotals`, but only the specified `teamName`, *e.g.*:

```js
function generateReportSummary(reportTotals, teamName) {
  if (reportTotals[teamName] > 5) {
    return `${teamName} surpassed goal with ${reportTotals[teamName]} reports`;
  } else {
    return undefined;
  }
}

var result1 = generateReportSummary({
  a_team: 12,
  b_team: 7,
  c_team: 0
}, 'b_team');
console.log('should log "b_team has surpassed goal with 7 reports":', result1);

var result2 = generateReportSummary({
  blue: 18,
  red: 8,
  green: 12
}, 'blue');
console.log('should log "blue has surpassed goal with 18 reports":', result2);

var result3 = generateReportSummary({
  gamma: 1,
  epsilon: 3,
  alpha: 4,
  bravo: 17
}, 'alpha');
console.log('Should log undefined, because function returned nothing:', result3);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is returning the first value is because you are never limiting the search according to the team name passed in.

```
for (key in reportTotals) {
    if (reportTotals[key] > 5) { // This will look at the key, regardless of whether that key matches the team name or not.
      return teamName + ' surpassed goal with ' + reportTotals[key] + ' reports'; // return will break the for ... in loop, causing the function to return and exit
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }
  }
```

The way your code is written, in `result1` for example, your `for...in` gets the first key: `a_team` and checks it's value: `12`. It determines that 12 is bigger than 5 and then returns the string referencing `teamName`.

You need to change the code so that it refers to the teamName for the value check.

There is several optimizations and error checks you could make, but to keep it simple let's just start with the current issue.

Since we know the `teamName` from the onset of the problem, we are simply going to check the `report` object for that team and it's corresponding score.

```
if ( reportTotals[teamName] && reportTotals[teamName] > 5) {
  return `${teamName} surpassed goal with ${reportTotals[teamName]} reports`;
} else {
  return undefined;
}
```

We are able to do this because we are looking for a specific value in the reportTotals, we don't need to loop through every key:value pair to find ours if we know the key's name. Instead, we check to see that the key is not undefined, and then we check the value attached to that key for a value of > 5.